# Library proxy with intelisense

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dllimport

I have quite odd scenario. I have external library like one below:
[image: external library]

Now I need to use it in other solution but in quite unnatural way (but it needs to be like that :/). So it is included in such fashion:
[image: included library]

As you noticed we have here new project named `ExternalLib` (just like the one we've created before in different solution). It contains only .dll of that library and we reference this project in `Consumer` (Add reference -> Project -> ExternalLib). Also I had to add one postbuild action for this 'proxy' ExternalLib `copy /Y "$(ProjectDir)/ExternalLib.dll" "$(TargetDir)"`. It builds without errors. Only errors are displayed by Visual Studio text editor (as it is visible on screenshot above).

My question: is there any way to make visual know about that 'real' contents of that library? (I also do not own .pdb files) I know it is really odd way including external library but it is some constraint I can't avoid :/

Comment: Curious why you haven't wrapped that external lib in a nuget packge and referenced it in the usual way?

Comment: I would really love to but it's impossible :/ in this particular case it needs to have that dummy project. In general .dll is provided by someone else and also someone else is building whole application with some custom made builder (not MSBuild).

Comment: Please update your question to include the information. so that others can fix it.